# GnuPG encrypt with private key

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg

Suppose I would like to encrypt a file with my private key for whatever reason so that only people with my public key can have access to the file. How would I do this?

```
gpg --sign --armor file
```

does not work because if you omit the --armor and use

```
gpg --sign --compress-level 0 file
```

the plaintext appears in the file.gpg.

```
gpg --encrypt file
```

will also not work because that uses public keys. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You unfortunately have got some fundamental misconceptions about the cryptography you want use. By definition if you want to asymmetrically encrypt some data you need to use the public key and the encrypted data can only be decrypted with the private key.

If you want to encrypt a message so that only a certain group of people can access it you can asymmetrically encrypt it with all the public keys of each individual in the group or encrypt it symmetrically with a random key and share that key with each individual in the group.

Answer (score -1):

You can encrypt your file symmetrically using your public key, so that everybody with access to your public key can decrypt your file.

Comment: This answer does not make sense.. Either you should encrypt the message with private key so that anybody with public key can verify it or anybody can encrypt message with public key so that only you can decrypt it.. 
I dont see option to encrypt with PUBLIC key so that it can be decrypted with PUBLIC key..